# Плавное перемещение спрайта SDL2

Tags: c#, .net, sdl2, dotnet-cli

Делаю сцену с эффектом parallax. Не могу сделать плавное перемещение спрайта по оси X. Проблема в том, что не зависимо от того, использую я `SDL_RenderCopyF` или `SDL_RenderCopy` спрайт при медленном перемещении отрисовывается согласно пиксельной сетке монитора, что сопровождается эффектом дрожания, когда слоев много и все перемещаются с разной скоростью.

Моя проблема похожа на [SDL2 Smooth texture(sprite) animation between points in time function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36746246/sdl2-smooth-texturesprite-animation-between-points-in-time-function)
Но там была версия SDL2 не поддерживающая отрисовку с плавающей точкой, и автору пришлось ее патчить. Начиная с версии 2.0.10.0 в SDL добавили `SDL_RenderCopyF`, `SDL_FRect` и другие функции, с помощью которой можно реализовать subpixel перемещение спрайтов, но я не могу добиться того, чтобы они работали в моей сцене.

Есть 10 слоев в разрешении FullHD. Отрисовка происходит в окно FullHD.

**Код инициализации окна и рендера:**

```
void CreateWidnow()
{
    var windowFlags = Settings.Fullscreen ?
        SDL.SDL_WindowFlags.SDL_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN : Settings.Resizeble ? 
        SDL.SDL_WindowFlags.SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE : SDL.SDL_WindowFlags.SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN;
        
    renderWindow = SDL.SDL_CreateWindow(
        Settings.DebugMode ? $"{Settings.Title} [DEBUG]" : Settings.Title, SDL.SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 
        SDL.SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
        Settings.Resolution.Width,
        Settings.Resolution.Height,              
        windowFlags);
}

void CreateRenderer()
{
    if(Settings.VSinc) {
        renderer = SDL.SDL_CreateRenderer(
            renderWindow, -1, 
            SDL.SDL_RendererFlags.SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC |
            SDL.SDL_RendererFlags.SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED |
            SDL.SDL_RendererFlags.SDL_RENDERER_TARGETTEXTURE
        );
    }
    else
    {
        renderer = SDL.SDL_CreateRenderer(
            renderWindow, -1, 
            SDL.SDL_RendererFlags.SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED |
            SDL.SDL_RendererFlags.SDL_RENDERER_TARGETTEXTURE
        );
    }   
}
```

**Основной цикл с расчетом `deltaTime`:**

```
void RenderLoop()
{
    bool cap = Settings.FPS > 0;
    var timer_fps = new Timer();
        
    ulong now_counter = SDL.SDL_GetPerformanceCounter();
    ulong last_counter = 0;
    double deltaTime = 0;
        
    while (renderLoop)
    {
        timer_fps.Start();
            
        last_counter = now_counter;
        now_counter = SDL.SDL_GetPerformanceCounter();
            
        deltaTime = (double)(now_counter - last_counter) / SDL.SDL_GetPerformanceFrequency();
            
        OnPreUpdate(deltaTime);
        OnUpdate(deltaTime);
        SDL.SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
        OnPostUpdate(deltaTime);
            
        if( ( cap ) && ( timer_fps.GetTicks() < 1000 / Settings.FPS ) )
        {
            SDL.SDL_Delay( ( 1000 / Settings.FPS  ) - timer_fps.GetTicks() );
        }
            
    }
}
```

**Код загрузки и отрисовки спрайта:**

```
public Sprite(string path)
{
    Path = path;
    Transform = new Transform(new Point(0, 0));
    sprite = Image.IMG_LoadTexture(Game.RenderContext, path);
    SDL.SDL_QueryTexture(sprite, out format, out access, out width, out height); // get the width and height of the texture

    draw_rect = new SDL.SDL_FRect();
    draw_rect.w = width;
    draw_rect.h = height;
    scr_rect.x = 0; scr_rect.y = 0; scr_rect.w = width; scr_rect.h = height; 
}

public Transform Transform
{
    get; set;
}

public void Draw()
{
    draw_rect.x = (float)Transform.Position.X;
    draw_rect.y = (float)Transform.Position.Y;
    SDL.SDL_RenderCopyExF(Game.RenderContext, sprite, ref scr_rect, ref draw_rect, Transform.Degrees, IntPtr.Zero, SDL.SDL_RendererFlip.SDL_FLIP_NONE);
}
```

**Функция перемещения (`Transform.Translate`):**

```
public void Translate(double x, double y)
{
    position.X += x;
    position.Y += y;
}
```

**Функция реализации параллакса (перемещаем спрайты обратно в правую сторону, когда они уходят за экран):**

```
void layerDraw(Sprite l1, Sprite l2, double speed)
{
    l1.Transform.Translate(speed, 0);
    l1.Draw();


    l2.Transform.Translate(speed, 0);
    l2.Draw();

    if (l1.Transform.Position.X <= -Settings.Resolution.Width)
        l1.Transform.SetPosition(Settings.Resolution.Width + l2.Transform.Position.X, 0);
    if (l2.Transform.Position.X <= -Settings.Resolution.Width)
        l2.Transform.SetPosition(Settings.Resolution.Width + l1.Transform.Position.X, 0);  
    }
```

**Функция отрисовки параллакса:**

```
double speed_09 = -2.0, speed_08 = -4.0, speed_07 = -8.0, speed_06 = -16.0;
double speed_05 = -24.0, speed_04 = -32.0, speed_03 = -64.0, speed_02 = -96.0, speed_01 = -128.0;

protected override void Update(double deltaTime)
{
    background.Draw();
    layerDraw(forest_091, forest_092, speed_09 * deltaTime);
    layerDraw(forest_081, forest_082, speed_08 * deltaTime);
    layerDraw(forest_071, forest_072, speed_07 * deltaTime);
    layerDraw(forest_061, forest_062, speed_06 * deltaTime);
    layerDraw(particles051, particles052, speed_05 * deltaTime);
    layerDraw(forest_041, forest_042, speed_04 * deltaTime);
    layerDraw(particles_031, particles_032, speed_03 * deltaTime);
    layerDraw(bushes_021, bushes_022, speed_02 * deltaTime);
    layerDraw(mist_011, mist_012, speed_01 * deltaTime);
}
```

**Вывод координат `forest_091` в консоль:**

```
[11:31:07:32] (x,y): = (1902,7461329999965:0), deltaTime = 0,001391, speed = -0,002782
[11:31:07:32] (x:y): = (1902,7430913999965:0), deltaTime = 0,0015208, speed = -0,0030416
[11:31:07:32] (x:y): = (1902,7400399999965:0), deltaTime = 0,0015257, speed = -0,0030514
[11:31:07:32] (x:y): = (1902,7370409999965:0), deltaTime = 0,0014995, speed = -0,002999
[11:31:07:32] (x:y): = (1902,7339605999964:0), deltaTime = 0,0015402, speed = -0,0030804
[11:31:07:33] (x:y): = (1902,7300727999964:0), deltaTime = 0,0019439, speed = -0,0038878
[11:31:07:33] (x:y): = (1902,7271281999963:0), deltaTime = 0,0014723, speed = -0,0029446
[11:31:07:33] (x:y): = (1902,7241953999962:0), deltaTime = 0,0014664, speed = -0,0029328
[11:31:07:33] (x:y): = (1902,7212207999962:0), deltaTime = 0,0014873, speed = -0,0029746
[11:31:07:33] (x:y): = (1902,7181395999962:0), deltaTime = 0,0015406, speed = -0,0030812
[11:31:07:33] (x:y): = (1902,715346599996:0), deltaTime = 0,0013965, speed = -0,002793
[11:31:07:33] (x:y): = (1902,712221399996:0), deltaTime = 0,0015626, speed = -0,0031252
[11:31:07:34] (x:y): = (1902,709382799996:0), deltaTime = 0,0014193, speed = -0,0028386
```

[Ссылка на youtube с демонстрацией проблемы](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kjoDMnizsdM)

**UPD:** Сглаживание может помочь в случае, если спрайты большие. В случае с Pixel Art сглаживание использовать не представляется возможным, и проблема возвращается. Я сделал небольшую демо сцену, с камерой плавно следящей за персонажем. В момент, когда камера заканчивает перемещение к персонажу, видно как спрайты начинают заметно "дребезжать", и пиксели рывками "переплывают" по координатной плоскости. Вот [запись](https://youtu.be/CYhqpEiUcdE) сцены. Там же можно скачать скомпилированную демку с нужными ресурсами. Полный код проекта можно посмотреть [здесь](https://github.com/edwardgushchin/Electron2D/tree/float_experiment)

P.S. Документацию и комментарии в коде я не подготовил, т.к. не рассчитывал открывать исходный код на данном этапе разработки, но оперативно отвечу на все возникающие вопросы. Сразу хочу сказать, что стоит обратить внимание на функцию Draw в классе [Sprite](https://github.com/edwardgushchin/Electron2D/blob/float_experiment/Graphics/Sprite.cs) т.к. там вызывается функция отрисовки `SDL_RenderCopyExF`.

Я использую nectcore3.1, [SDL2-CS](https://github.com/flibitijibibo/SDL2-CS) и SDL2 v2.0.10.0

Answer (score 2):

Проблема заключалась в выключенном сглаживании.
Вот эта строчка перед отрисовкой спрайтов сделала мою анимацию плавной:

```
SDL.SDL_SetHint( SDL.SDL_HINT_RENDER_SCALE_QUALITY, "2");
```

**UPD:** Сглаживание может помочь в случае, если спрайты большие. В случае с Pixel Art сглаживание использовать не представляется возможным, и проблема возвращается. Я сделал небольшую демо сцену, с камерой плавно следящей за персонажем. В момент, когда камера заканчивает перемещение к персонажу, видно как спрайты начинают заметно "дребезжать", и пиксели рывками "переплывают" по координатной плоскости. Вот [запись](https://youtu.be/CYhqpEiUcdE) сцены. Там же можно скачать скомпилированную демку с нужными ресурсами. Полный код проекта можно посмотреть [здесь](https://github.com/edwardgushchin/Electron2D/tree/float_experiment)

P.S. Документацию и комментарии в коде я не подготовил, т.к. не рассчитывал открывать исходный код на данном этапе разработки, но оперативно отвечу на все возникающие вопросы. Сразу хочу сказать, что стоит обратить внимание на функцию Draw в классе [Sprite](https://github.com/edwardgushchin/Electron2D/blob/float_experiment/Graphics/Sprite.cs) т.к. там вызывается функция отрисовки `SDL_RenderCopyExF`.